Custom aspx page in IIS showing error 500 this page isnt working
There are custom aspx pages deployed from the previous developer under the custom folder in IIS that when we access from SharePoint 2016, are throwing this error:

I am not familiar how this page is deployed nor am I an advanced developer. After seeking Microsoft's help, they managed to pull this error message from the tracing log, but they unable to assist further.

Can someone provide some insights on what went wrong? Or how is a custom page like this is deployed?

The error is:
Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type "add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'Session'
Check the web.config file within the custom folder and search for line with duplicate name property with value Session. It's probably around <system.webServer><modules> or <appSettings>.
Sample:
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="Session" type="MyCompany, MyCustom" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    <add name="Session" type="MyCompany, MyCustom" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    <add name="MyCustomError" type="MyCompany, MyCustom" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>

After identifying and deleting the duplicate lines, you will have to investigate on how these lines have been created (event receiver, feature activation, PowerShell script, installation of CU, etc.)
